# What happens when I click "Blame Differences" in TortoiseSVN log?

Tags: tortoisesvn

when I was checking the latest difference in code in SVN Log, accidently I clicked blame differences insted of show differences. Now, when I check the log again I do not see anything visible related to my blaming.

Do you know what exactly happens when you blame a difference? Does it effect the repository and if yes, how can I undo that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My understanding of blame, is that it shows you who last modified a given line in a given file so you can determine which person to blame for that change. It does not change anything on the server side.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.blame.html

Comment: Thanks.

also in http://www.scribd.com/doc/6793213/TortoiseSVN14 page 89, there is a nice description.

Comment: Thanks for that nice link! I did not think of looking into the documentation of the tortoiseSVN client.

Answer (score 1):

In short: blaming shows you, who made which changes were to a file. Ususally the last changes will be shown for a given file for a simple blame report. If you choses to show the blame for a diff of two revisions, you will get the diff of the blame reports for the changes.

But there is no change in the repository.

Take a look at chapter

> 4.23. Who Changed Which Line?

in the TortoiseSVN help file.