# Why is SVN blame difference with TortoiseSVN blame

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to use svn blame to get a same result of TortoiseSVN blame, but I found they are very difference, such as **revision, author, code**... they are **not same**!

I know TortoiseSVN is a GUI software, so I want to know what happened after I clicked "OK" on TortoiseSVN blame GUI so that it's very difference with svn blame command in commandline.

**This is my SVN command:**

```
svn blame "https://file-on-svn-repo" -r 1:HEAD
```

**Here is my TortoiseSVN options:**

- From revision: 1
- To Revision: HEAD revision
- Diff options: Ignore line endings
- Diff options: Ignore all whitespaces
- Use text viewer to view blames

I promise the files both svn blame and TortoiseSVN blame are same.

Can someone tell me why they are difference or how can I make a same output like TortoiseSVN? I want author, revision and code of `svn blame` output or some other command output be same with TortoiseSVN blame, if no command could implement it directly, please tell me the logic that how can I implement it.

I found a question on Stackoverflow but the answers are not what I want: [What happens when I click "Blame Differences" in TortoiseSVN log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623757/what-happens-when-i-click-blame-differences-in-tortoisesvn-log)
I used `svn blame "http://file-on-repo"` first, but I found it's diffrence with TortoiseSVN, so I changed it to `svn blame "http://file-on-repo" -r 1:HEAD`, but it's still different.I also chose "Use text viewer to view blames", but the text in notepad is still not same with svn blame output.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what the difference is, in case it isn't an explicit design decision by TortoiseSVN authors.

Comment: Sorry maybe my English is not good so that I didn't expressed what I want. I mean the difference between `svn blame` output and TurtoiseSVN blame is author & revision & code not same. I want svn could have a same output like TortoiseSVN. @ÁlvaroGonzález

Comment: Do you mean that one of the tools reports incorrect information, every time? Which one is right and which one is wrong? Can you reproduce it if you create a test repo?

Comment: I didn't mean which one was wrong before because the code is not written by me. But now I found that `svn blame` gives me a wrong output everytime, maybe I'm on a wrong way to use `svn blame`, I will try to find the result and update it later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you activated the options

- Diff options: Ignore line endings
- Diff options: Ignore all whitespaces

you have to do that with the svn blame command as well:

```
svn blame "https://file-on-svn-repo" -r 1:HEAD -x -w -x --ignore-eol-style
```

Answer (score 1):

Stefan is right. Finally, I solved this problem using `svn blame -x -w "https://file-on-svn-repo -r 1:HEAD"`